# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed. How to display json response

Tags: angular, typescript, api, frontend

I'm trying to display JSON response but I get this error:
core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed.

[Error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weLZ3.png)

How can I solve this issue? How can I convere it to array ?

TS

```
export interface Book {
  id: number,
  book_name: string,
  book_issue: Date,

}
```

Service.ts

```
export class BookApiService {
  private bookUrl  = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/books"
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }
    constructor (private http: HttpClient){}

    getBook(): Observable<Book[]> {
      return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.bookUrl ,this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      )
      }
  
  errorHandler(error) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
 }
```

template

```
<ul *ngFor="let book of books">
    <li>{{book.book_name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  books: Book[] = [];

  constructor(public rs : BookApiService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rs.getBook().subscribe((data: Book[])=>{
      this.books = data;
      console.log(this.books);
    })  
  }
```

Backend API Response:

```
{"books":[{"book_issue":"Fri, 13 Mar 2020","book_name":"Book1","id":1},
{"book_issue":"Fri, 13 Mar","book_name":"Book2",                                                                                                                                                                                                "id":2}],
"success":true}
```

and this is the console log:
[console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAqU0.png)

Comment: *ngFor="let book of books.books"..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code as below :

```
<ul *ngFor="let book of books?.books">
    <li>{{book.book_name}}</li>
</ul>
```

The response returned from your API is an `object` and you are assigning it to the variable used in `ngFor` , which expects an array.
so its throwing error.

Another way to solve this would be to assign your variable as below :

```
this.rs.getBook().subscribe((data: any)=>{
      this.books = data.books;
      console.log(this.books);
    })
```

and then in your `html` use this as below :

```
<ul *ngFor="let book of books">
    <li>{{book.book_name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @FaDATA yeah  you should remove `Book[]` because you are not getting response as an array

Comment: It Is better to create an interface BooksModel{books: Book[] }and return the Observable<BooksModel>.

Comment: Of if possible to change the api reponse to return the data that must be used.

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
getBooks(): Observable<Book []> {
  return this.http.get<{books: Book[]}>(this.bookUrl, this.httpOptions)
           .pipe(
              map(response => response.books)
            )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said the following is the Response:

```
{"books":[{"book_issue":"Fri, 13 Mar 2020","book_name":"Book1","id":1},
{"book_issue":"Fri, 13 Mar","book_name":"Book2",                                                                                                                                                                                                "id":2}],
"success":true}
```

that is wrong since the object you get is not a array of books.

It is a JSON Object with the Key **books** that contains a Array of books.

If this is the case:

**EDIT** you do can do this, since the response does not give you an array in the body:

```
this.rs.getBook().subscribe((data: object)=>{
      this.books = data['books'];
      console.log(this.books);
    })
```

or you could define a wrapper class:

```
export class BookResponse{
 books: Book[];
 success: boolean;
}

    getBook(): Observable<Book[]> {
      return this.http.get<BookResponse>(this.bookUrl ,this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      ).pipe(map(body => body.books))
      }

this.rs.getBook().subscribe((data: Book[])=>{
      this.books = data;
      console.log(this.books);
    })
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution because the service says that the method should return an Observable of Book array. In this case is not and this is a bit inconsistent from my point of view.

Comment: then the restmethod needs to return a `Observable<{[string]:Book[]]}>`  or even `Observable<object>` . The REST-Endpoint dictats how the corrosponding rest interfaces should look like. if the Entpoint returns a array you should use an array. but you get a Wrapper with a key that contains a array. this will not be properly converted, since JavaScript/Typscript is not typesafe. It will parse the object like it is, even if you want an Array. You still get an Object with a key that cointains an array of books.  You can also define a Corrosponding object to the endpoint response.

Comment: I agree that this also solve the problem, but I guess the answer from @markpenaranda is the best for this special case.

Comment: @RicardoFerreira it depends. You still have a service that indicates that you get a restcall and EXPECT an array. But you do not get an Array as Response. either you map it via `pipe(map(response = >response.books))` to the desired field or you redefine the call to a proper responsebody type.  
Thats the whole reason why angular Uses Typescript in the first place. You should define what you get and get what you expect via definition.

Comment: Yes, but right now the consumer is receiving a Book[ ] and not an object anymore. the map is returning what is expected. Of course it could be better to create a interface with the api response, or even better to change the api to return what is expected.